# php automation with curl_exec

Tags: php, php-curl

I need to execute some php pages with curl_exec but I'm getting the message "Moved Permanently" and the pages isn't executing.

What Am I forgetting?

I have all the pages in one mysql table and my code is bellow:

```
<?php
include('server.php');
$results_path = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table_script");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results_path)) {

$file_string = $row['url'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

if(($html = curl_exec($ch)) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    die('111');
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;

}
?>
```

Comment: Well that message comes with a code, but as it is generated by the server you are attempting to contact, I would start by checking the `url` column in that table holds accurate and current urls

Comment: Thanks @MarkusZeller. That's worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the location if there is a redirect. You can accomplish that by simply add this line before the execute.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Note, to correct the curl handle on line

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```